# dataflow read files in DoFn with output as stream of lines

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

Dataflow Streaming Pipeline:

Some Source Upload Compressed Files in GCS -> Upload Event (gs:///folder/file.gz) Sent to PubSub -> DataFlow Streaming Read file Event from PubSub I/O -> DoFn Un-Gzip

```
static class CustomDoFn extends DoFn<String, String>{

@Override
public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
    String gcsPath = c.element();
    Open ReadChannel with GCS
    Get Stream from Channel
    while((line = stream.ReadLine()) != null){
        c.output(line) // Is this good way to read and send line down the pipeline?
    }
}
```

// to-be Pipeline

```
 pipeline.apply(PubSubIO.Read()).
           apply(ParDO.of(new CustomDoFn())).
           apply(new CustomTX()).
           apply(BigQueryIO.Write());
```

Doubts are:
1. Is it correct method to produce output in loop in DoFn?
2. How I can use make use of [FileBasedSource.FileBasedReader](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/FileBasedSource.java) inside Dofn  ?

Comment: Hello, I just want to make sure that I understand your question. Do you want to create a streaming pipeline that reads from files? And you want to  use Pub/Sub to receive filenames and read them? Are your file sizes very large? One issue with the way that you are reading the file and outputing each line, is that the whole file must be read into memory before it is actually emitted. For large files this doesn't work and can OOM.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to use a FileBasedSource with dynamic filenames (i.e. file names not specified at pipeline construction).  A future improvement to Apache Beam 2.0 (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-65) will enable this feature but is not yet ready for use.  Your outlined approach will, as Alex Amato pointed out, be memory-constrained for large files, but should otherwise produce a functioning pipeline.

Comment: There is now a more specific JIRA filed for this use case, and we're getting close to being able to implement it https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-2511 TextIO should support reading a PCollection of filenames